Net Core 8.0 Как скомпилировать проект в единый файл с малым размером
Всё никак не получается скомпилировать сборку в единый файл .exe без раздутого размера, всегда получается то 12 мб с оптимизацией, то 60 МБ без оптимизации, что не так делаю?
Я пробую через .csproj
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
    <StartupObject>TestingNetCore.Program</StartupObject>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained> 
  </PropertyGroup>

Но использование PublishSingleFile не даёт результата.
Подскажите, как скомпилировать сборку в один файл без раздутости?

Важен размер - откажитесь от .NET вовсе, собирайте в нативный код (AOT). Ну а 12 мб -  это очень хороший размер (если не учитывать конечно несколько сотен мб лежащего на компе .NET...).

Нужно больше информации, чтобы понять, почему у вас такой разброс: от 12 до 60 Мб. Надеюсь, вы Release публикуете? / Не знаю, какой минимальный размер может быть у обычного SingleFile .NET экзешника, но у AOT он может быть меньше полутора мегабайт. Native AOT (не пугайтесь размеру статьи, прочитайте только этот раздел).

@AlexanderPetrov, конечно в Release! У меня .exe файл весит 140 кб, а .dll файл 5 кб. в итоге после published должен быть размер в 145 кб, верно? Я использовал как с true чтобы убрать лишний размер в 12 мб получается и без то получается в 60 мб общий сбор. Вот как сделать чтобы корректно было в один .exe без такого огромного объёма мб
